# Ubuntu system won’t boot with error “Failed to start Create Volatile Files and Directories + Network Time Synchronisation”

Tags: linux, ubuntu, temporary-files

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS and when I start my latpop, the screen stops at

```
[Failed] Failed to start Create Volatile Files and Directories.  
See 'systemctl status systemd-temfiles-setup.service' for details  
[ .... ]  

[Failed] Failed to start Network Time Synchronisation.   
See 'systemctl status systemd-timesyncd.service' for details  
[...]
```

I'm running the command shell from Ubuntu Recovery Mode.

Answer (score -3):

You won't be able to use your usual command shell hence
1. Restart your Ubuntu in Recovery Mode. You can do so by choosing Open Ubuntu with Advanced Option from your Grub menu

2. For me, this issue occured because, I had wrongfully given access of some system files to `username` instead of my `root`
   There are other ways you you could get this issue so, definitely check out other resources as well.

**Solution**
0. You can check your ownership of `/` and `/var` folder

```
$ stat -c "%U %G" /
or,
$ stat -c "%U %G" /var/
```

You might be getting,
`username username`

1. Start with giving ownership back to root
   `$ chown -R root:root /`
   it'll take a few minutes
2. Remount.
   `$ mount -o remount,rw /`
3. Restart these services.

   - Tmpfiles-setup Services
     `$ systemctl start systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service`
   - Timesyncd Service
     `$ systemctl start systemd-timesyncd.service`
4. Reboot
   `$ reboot`

If this didn't solve the issue for you, you might want to look [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=196341) and then [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissionsACLs)

I hope this helped. Be well!

Comment: WARNING!!! DO NOT FOLLOW THESE STEPS!!! `chown -R root:root /`
WILL break any Linux system and there is no way to undo the damage in Debian distros. You will most likely have to reinstall the OS if you follow this guide!

Comment: Not everything belongs to root. Some services set permissions to files and directories restricted to its specific user and/or group, therefore when you blindly change the ownership to `root` these service will fail.